# DKMS error when installing amd drivers

Tags: 12.10, ati, fglrx, dkms

I need to install AMD drivers in my Ubuntu 12.10.

I followed [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/129200#129200) (and I installed all dependencies from 12.04 guide)

Here is my logs:

```
Check if system has the tools required for installation.
Uninstalling any previously installed drivers.

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.98/source ->
                 /usr/src/fglrx-8.98

DKMS: add completed.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area....
cd /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.98/build; sh make.sh --nohints --uname_r=3.5.0-17-generic --norootcheck.....(bad exit status: 1)
[Error] Kernel Module : Failed to build fglrx-8.98 with DKMS
[Error] Kernel Module : Removing fglrx-8.98 from DKMS

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 8.98
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
[Reboot] Kernel Module : update-initramfs
```

Any ideas what im missing?

Comment: Do you have the headers and build-essential packages? The dependencies that were explained in the 12.04 method?

Comment: Try directly executing `cd /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.98/build; sh make.sh --nohints --uname_r=3.5.0-17-generic --norootcheck`, then reporting why it failed here.

Answer (score 1):

You should have `linux-headers` installed for *every* kernel version you have installed (and can see in `grub-advanced` menu while booting). Although check that you have `build-essential` package and that `gcc -v` runs well.

Finally, it can be an error in this package, for example it can disagree with gcc version and settings.